# problem creating pivot table in vba/excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving a

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

This is the part of my code that VBA says there is a problem with:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "WIP_Table", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
            "Hours1 Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable_Hours1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can often be fixed by splitting up the operation into discrete steps:

```
dim pc as pivotcache, pt as pivottable

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                           "WIP_Table", Version:=6)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Hours1 Pivot'!R1C1", _
                             TableName:="PivotTable_Hours1", DefaultVersion:=6)
```

Comment: VBA highlights the last block of code (of your three blocks)

Comment: That worksheet name has spaces so likely needs to be enclosed in single quotes. `TableDestination:="'Hours1 Pivot'!R1C1` or something like that.